# What can I use for schach?

Tags: halacha, sukkah, architecture-design, schach

What materials can be used for the top of a Sukkah?

Answer (score 7):

Trees branches and bamboo poles are popular.  I most prefer evergreen tree branches because they look the prettiest and may even have a nice aroma.  Anything that grows from the ground and is not 'mekabel tumah' is a candidate for scach.  Fruit is an example of an item that is 'mekabel tumah.'

mekabel tumah = something that can become ritually impure

Answer (score 7):

> Anything that grows from the ground
>   and is not 'mekabel tumah' is a
>   candidate for scach[*sic*].

These are two of the three basic requirements. The last is that the material not be *[currently](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Mishnah/Seder%5FMoed/Tractate%5FSukkah/Chapter%5F1/4)* attached to the ground. This disqualifies, for example, building a suka next to a vineyard and stretching some vines (which fill the other two criteria) over as the covering.

By the way, according to many opinions, even non-wide processed wood (e.g. [firring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firring) strips) may be used, provided there is [sufficient spacing](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Mishnah/Seder%5FMoed/Tractate%5FSukkah/Chapter%5F1/7) between them.

Answer (score 4):

To tie the schach in place, many people/places use plastic cable ties, as they're not "mekabel tumah."  Some rabbis consider this not the preferred way, as the tie-downs should ideally also be plant matter.