# Which plants are most suitable for sukkah roofing?

Tags: product-recommendation, sukkot, agriculture, how-to

In South Africa palm branches are very popular as schach because they stay green for long and cover a lot of space per branch. Many palm branch sellers advertise around sukkot time, and every year the price creeps up.

I would like to grow my own schach, but palm trees grow very tall and eventually will not fit in my garden. Which other plants/trees provide appropriate foliage that will cover a large area and preferably stay green for a week after being detached? What is used for schach in other parts of the world?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/24/what-can-i-use-for-schach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bamboo is very popular, since you can reuse it from year to year.

I also like wood lath like [this](http://www.kalinichfenceco.com/lathwood.asp) or [this](http://www.menards.com/main/building-materials/lumber/construction-lumber/wood-stakes-bridging/42-48-wood-lath-bundle/p-1398620.htm), it covers better than bamboo (less space in between).

Palm is quite idea for schach, other than that you can try evergreens. Do not use evergreens with needles for leaves (like pine) - they always fall and are unpleasant. Instead look for leaves like the cypress, which are arranged in sprays.

Bad leaves:
[image: Bad leaves]

Good leaves:
[image: Good leaves]

You will need to go a local nursery to see which evergreens grow well in your area, and pay special attention to the leaves.