# Deeper meaning behind the schach on the sukkah

Tags: sources-mekorot, sukkah, schach

The Rambam (Laws of Sukkah and Lulav, 4:7) writes:

> A sukkah that does not possess a roof is invalid

This is from a halachic perspective. However, I was wondering what the deeper meaning behind the roof of the sukkah is. A obvious reason would be that we are under Hashem's protection, but is there more to it and to the [greenery](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/23483/27180) we place on top of the schach? Why do we put leaves on top of it....

What's the reasoning behind all this? Especially since Rav Hirsch [is quoted](https://ohr.edu/ask_db/ask_main.php/250/Q1/) in saying that a roof, "with its ability to shut out the heavenly influences of rain and sun, symbolizes man's imagined independence from G-d".

Comment: IMHO you should have quoted the coninuation of your linked article that says, "The symbol of the roof stands in diametric opposition to the weak succah-booth. **A succah, covered only by some meager branches, symbolizes our dependence on G-d.**

Comment: Yet, we have a full roof with leaves on top of it. So I don't understand that it a roof with meager branches symbolizes dependence on G-d.

Comment: https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/4515333/jewish/Why-Is-the-Sukkah-Covered-With-Plant-Material-Schach.htm

Comment: @Shmuel Why don't you live in a house with sechach on top it rather than a roof?

Comment: Well that seems obvious. But I am still looking for sources that discuss the deeper meaning behind it. And maybe some other than Rav Hirsch.

Comment: I believe Rav Hirsch is saying that is why a sukkah cannot have a real roof, only a temporary plant-based covering.

Comment: @N.T. interesting. Could you please elaborate? Rav Hirsch is only partly quoted there.